# How to structure angular factor/service that manipulates DOM

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dom, angularjs-directive, angular-services

I'm building a growl like UI in angular. I'd like to expose it as a factory (or service) to make it available in my controllers. Calling growl.add will result in a change in the DOM, so it seems like I should have a directive take care of that, rather than doing direct DOM manipulation in the factory. Assuming that a factory-directive combo is the best option (and please correct me if that is not a good assumption), the question is:

How best to communicate between the factory and the directive?

Specifically, how best to send messages *from* the factory to the directive? Other questions have well covered sending information the other way, with onetime callback.

See below the working example. I suspect there is a better way though..

For reference, I have played with other options:

A) have the directive watch the service, e.g.

```
$scope.$watch(function(){
     growl.someFunctionThatGetsNewData()},
  function(newValue){
    //update scope
  })
```

But this means that someFunctionThatGetsNewData gets called in every digest cycle, which seem wasteful, since we know that the data only gets changed on growl.add

B) send an 'event', either via routescope, or via event bindings on the dom/window. Seem un-angular

Since neither of those options seem good, I'm using the one below, but it still feels hacky. The `register` function means that the directive and the factory are tightly coupled. But then again from *usage* perspective they *are* tightly bound - one is no good w/o the other.

It seem like the ideal solution would involve declaring a factory (or service) that includes the directive in its declaration (and perhaps functional scope) so that it exposes a single public interface. It seems icky to have two separate publicly declared components that entirely depend on each other, and which have tight coupling in the interfaces.

## Working example - but there must be a better way..

```
vpModule.directive('vpGrowl',['$timeout', 'growl', function ($timeout, growl) {
return {
  template: '<div>[[msg]]</div.',
  link: function($scope, elm, attrs) {

     growl.register(function(){
        $scope.msg = growl.msg;
     });

     $scope.msg = growl.msg;

  }
};   
}]);


vpModule.factory('growl', ['$rootScope', '$sce', function($rootScope, $sce) {

  var growl = {};
  growl.msg = '';
  var updateCallback = function(){};

  growl.add = function(msg){
    growl.msg = msg;
    updateCallback();
  };

  growl.register = function(callback){
    updateCallback = callback;
  };

  return growl;
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would have your growl service decide what to show, not the directive. So, the service handles any timers, state, etc. to decide when to hide/show messages. The service then exposes a collection of messages which the directive simply binds to.

The directive can inject the service and simply place it in scope, and then bind an ng-repeat to the service's collection. Yes, this does involve a watch, but you *really* don't need to worry about the performance of a single watch like this.

`link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
    scope.growl = growl; // where 'growl' is the injected service
  }`

and then in the directive template:

`<div ng-repeat="msg in growl.messages">
     ...
  </div>`

Comment: thanks. this works. i'd initially tested something like this and it hadnt worked - the difference was that i was binding to a primitive type. e.g. $scope = growl.aStringValue. But $scope = growl.anObject work, so I guess the watchers work differently for primitives. If anyone can point to angular documentation on this I'd love to read it.

While this answer is a sufficient answer to this question, I'd still like to see a better way to couple a directive and a service into a single entity.

Comment: This technique will work with a string, object, collection, whatever. I suspect the problem you had is that you did something like scope.messages = growl.messages, and then bind to messages. This is different from scope.growl = growl, and bind to growl.messages, because the way I did it, the watch is on the *service's* collection, whereas in the other way the watch is on the *scope's copy of the service's* collection, which doesn't get updated.

Comment: As a followup on the issue of architecture, I think this approach separates concerns properly for Angular. The service is in charge of the logical/data concerns (what growl message are there, when do they expire, etc.). The directive is in charge of how to render the messages.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement following logic:

1. Service `growl` defines some property `growlProp` on `$rootScope` & update it on each call of growl.add
2. Directive set watcher on `$rootScope.growlProp`

So directive knows nothing about service & service knows nothing about directve.

And additional overhead related to watcher is minimum.

Comment: while this would work, it's the equivalent of 'put it in global scope', which is not very angular IMO